# Does get_query_var('cat') fetches child Category Posts as well?

Tags: php, wordpress

In category.php I am using custom query to get posts:

```
                <?php

                    $cat_id = get_query_var('cat'); 
                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 2,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'cat' => $cat_id
                    );

                    query_posts($args);
                    // the Loop
                    get_template_part('aa_HomeLoopMain');

                ?>
```

I am using `get_query_var('cat')` to get category post of current category and I think this would only give Category Posts of category id with `$cat_id` but not it's **child category posts**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object, reruns queries and is slow which all negatively impacts on performance and SEO and other functions that relies on the main query. Also, if this is your main query, you should not be using a custom query at all, you should be using `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query before it executes.

`get_query_var(`cat`)` only returns the queried category, not its children.

You should remove the `query_posts` part and add the following to your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin()
         && $q->is_main_query()
         && $q->is_category()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    }
});
```

### EDIT

You should query a total of 6 posts, I have updated my as such. You can try the following with your loop

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        if ( 1 <= $wp_query->current_post ) {
            // Add your markup for column one, this will display 2 posts
        } else {
            // Add your markup for column two, this will display 4 posts
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT 2

For some reason I cannot post comments from my mobile, but I think you are using the code wrongly. I have updated my code to show the loop. It does work. If it does not, something else is breaking your page like `query_posts`

Comment: Thanks! +1.. One more question: In column 1 I am displaying `2 posts` and in column 2 i am displaying `4 posts`, how do you suggest doing that?

Comment: It's always going in `else` part. Not sure why.. 

`var_dump($wp_query->current_post)` gives `int(-1)`

Comment: May be you should post another new question.